# Cannot install Jazzy Cocoapod

Tags: cocoapods, osx-yosemite, jazzy

I'm trying to install the Jazzy Cocoapod so I can use it to document my Swift code.  I have Cocoapods 0.35 successfully installed, but Jazzy will not install.  I looked for the log files that should have been produced but they are not present.  Here's the error message:

$ sudo gem install jazzy
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jazzy:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150130-37462-1halfop.rb extconf.rb
```

checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
/Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
    from /Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'
    from /Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/https.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'
    from /Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.1/lib/mini_portile.rb:3:in`'
    from /Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
    from /Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in`rescue in require'
    from /Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:395:in`'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.0.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out

Can anybody help me decipher this?  Thank you.

Comment: Did you check the Issues section of the project on GitHub? There are literally tons of questions by people who can't install/run jazzy for one reason or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following first:

```
xcode-select install
```

This solved the issue for me.

Update: I just saw how old this question was, but I guess it doesn't matter :).